# Loader on start and completion of Ajax Calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is probably a fairly basic jQuery question to ask, but after 12+ hours working through various jQuery code, deciphering what does and does not work in various jQuery versions, this one has stumped me. I'm working on 1.9.1 as this seems to be the most stable for every other plugin I am taking advantage of.

I want to add a class and an image to a specified container when an Ajax request starts, thus I believe I can use ajaxStart, and remove the class with ajaxComplete.

I will be using the function several times, as the entire site is based on loading the content by Ajax, so am looking to simplify this as much as possible.

At present, nothing happens. I click the 'buttonid' and nothing happens, the error console notifies "myajaxfunc is not a function". Here's where I'm at so far:-

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({ 
        $.fn.myajaxfunc = function() {
            $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
                this
                .addClass("loader");
                .append('<img src="images/loader-icon.gif">');
            }).ajaxStop(function() {
        .removeClass("loader"); 
            });​
        });
    });
});
```

I am then trying to call this 'myajaxfunc' function, like this:-

```
    $("#buttonid").click(function(){
        $('.main-content').myajaxfunc();

    $.ajax({url:"path/to/content.html",dataType:"html",success:function(result){
        $(".main-content").html(result);

        }});                
    });
```

Where am I going wrong? Ideally I would like to be able to call "myajaxfunc" on several click events, because I have a dozen menu items, each of which has a click function which puts content gotten via ajax into the main content area, so calling it like .myajaxfunc() seems the best, simplest way forward, I think.

Comment: `    .   removeClass("loader");  `

Comment: Your syntax for extend is completely wrong.  You should be seeing script error in the console.  You need an object definition for the argument and hint, there is no `=` in an object definition.

Comment: The code as it currently is does not even add the 'loader' class or the image. I guess this problem has to be figured out first before I have to worry about removing it...alas, I've fixed it in the the OP, poor formatting technique when copy/pasting to here. Thanks!

Comment: Also, I loosely based this around 'a really simple plugin tutorial' from here:- http://www.queness.com/post/112/a-really-simple-jquery-plugin-tutorial, not really sure how the extend syntax is completely wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Final working solution, including error statuses, seems to work well:-

```
 $.fn.extend({
     myajaxfunc: function () {

     this.each(function () {
         var element = $(this);
         $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
            element.empty().append('<img src="images/loader-icon.gif">').addClass("loader");
         }).ajaxStop(function () {
            $(this).unbind("ajaxStart");
            element.removeClass("loader");
         }).ajaxError(function (e,xhr,opt) {     
            element.empty().append('<h1>AJAX Failed!</h1>').removeClass("loader");
            element.appendTo('<p><strong>Location:</strong> '+ opt.url + '</p><p><strong>Status Code:</strong> ' + xhr.status + '</p><p><strong>Reason:</strong> ' + xhr.statusText + '</p></div>');
         });
     });
     }
 });
```

Call it:-

```
$("#buttonid").click(function(){

    $('.main-content').myajaxfunc();

    $.ajax({url:"path/to/file.html",dataType:"html",success:function(result){
        $(".main-content").html(result);
    }});

});
```

I also added an unbind method so that this only happens on the initial page load, which allows me to use other AJAX again for small changes on the newly loaded page without having the overlay again.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in this way and this is working fine at my end.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   $("#Loading").ajaxStart(function () {
    $(this).show();
    });

   $("#Loading").ajaxStop(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Here #Loading is the id of loader image that you want to show or hide.

Comment: This way would mean I would need to put <img id="Loading" src="image.jpg" style="display:none;"> in the HTML code. How would this apply the required CSS class and, more importantly, allow the re-use of the code on various click methods?

Comment: You can put this code in common lay out of your application and it will shown work whenever any ajax call performed. Or if you want to add css here you can use this code like. <img id="Loading" src="image.jpg" class="hideLoader"> hideloader will initially hide this image and $("#Loading").ajaxStart(function () {
    $(this).removeClass("hideLoader").addClass("showLoader");
    });

   $("#Loading").ajaxStop(function () {
    $(this).removeClass("showLoader").addClass("hideLoader");
    });

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle with this complete? I'm not sure how this applies to my requirement here...

Comment: -1: 4 upvotes *voted in pairs at the same time* is not a coincidence: `As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxStart() method should only be attached to document.` This question specifies jQuery 1.9.1 so this answer would never work!

Answer (score 2):

I have done this in this way and it's work fine for me.

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    $('#DivProgress').show();
});
$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    $('#DivProgress').hide();
});
```

where DivProgress is the id of the div where the loader is defined.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the namespace within fn.extend
So:
'$.fn.extend({methodyouwannaaddd})'

Or remove the extend alltogether and just define the method:
'$.fn.methodyouwannaadd'

Comment: I removed the fn.extend line, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the way you are defining the extension method. The following may work better.

```
$.fn.extend({
 myajaxfunc: function () {

     this.each(function () {
         var ele = $(this);
         $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
             ele.addClass("loader").append('<img src="images/loader-icon.gif">');
         }).ajaxStop(function () {
             ele.removeClass("loader");
         });


     });

 }});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this still creates the error "TypeError: $(...).myajaxfunc is not a function"

Comment: That seems to work for the most part, with the exception of the image. I have seen the jsfiddle works, but if you add in .append('<img src="images/loader-icon.gif"'> the class is added and removed correctly, but the image is never inserted anywhere.

Comment: The image is added, you're just not seeing it. I've updated the jFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/cjM77/6/

Answer (score 0):

use [ajax global events](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/)

```
$(document).bind("ajaxSend", function () {
   //Show loader....
}).bind("ajaxStop", function () {
   //hide loader....
}).bind("ajaxError", function () {
   //hide loader....
});
```